# Pronunciation of "Porsche" over time

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Is there an official pronunciation for Porsche? I grew up pronouncing it with a silent final e ("Porsh"). However, I've increasingly heard it was pronunced with a neutral e sound at the end ("Por-shuh").

Is this simply an anomaly in some people's idiolects, is it regional, or is it becoming a general thing in American English? And has the pronunciation with the final e become more common over time?

Comment: "[…] My friends all drive Porsches, I must make amends."

Comment: Like [this](http://youtu.be/4OuPY-1snyw).

Comment: It goes like this: if you own one, you pronounce the e. If you don't, you don't.

Comment: Heh @Sam - so it's not regional, it's...posessional.

Comment: @Gnawme OK, but only if you pronounce Mercedes like [this](http://youtu.be/mB5CKXoqJLY)

Comment: @sarah Ja, I worked with a girl from Deutschland whose name I thought (for the longest time) was Zides; turned out her full name was Mercedes...

Comment: As Mercedes has been mentioned too: "Oh Lord, won't you buy me a Mercedes Benz? My friends all drive Porshes, I must make amends."

Comment: When I first heard BBC newsreaders use the name (in the context of motor racing) I thought of it as 'Portia' like the Shakespeare character; it took me a while to realise it was Porsche.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Car guys and gearheads have (pretty much) always known how to pronounce **Por**-*sche*.

Porsche's [television ads](http://youtu.be/ud2cctCbTik) have always given the proper pronunciation, so anyone who paid attention to them (which may have been limited to car guys and gearheads) knew the proper pronunciation.

I would speculate that Porsche has reached a broader market in the past decade or two, especially with the introduction of the Cayenne crossover in 2003, and so there have been more Porsche ads on television, giving a larger cross-section of people (not just the ones who watched F1 or GTP) exposure to the proper pronunciation.

Comment: The Longman dictionary (among others) suggests that [pɔː(r)ʃ] is the most common pronunciation. The fact that the German language actually has two different schwa sounds (compare Lehrer and Lehre) leads to confusion regarding the correct pronunciation of the e in Porsche. In the English Porsche commercials, the pronunciation of the e matches the German one. However, that pronunciation is not Por-shuh (equivalent to [pɔːrʃə]). The appropriate schwa in this case sounds very much like the e in test, chef, let, and is identical to the final e in German words such as lehre, halte, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing about English is, or can be, "official". Sorry.

And *Porsche* is a German name, not an English one.

The German pronunciation is something like ['pɔəʃə].

How one pronounces a foreign name in English depends on how closely one wishes to reproduce the foreign pronunciation. This varies a **lot**, especially among Americans, who are usually innocent of any linguistic knowledge.

A German /r/ is hard to make for rhotic English speakers (though non-rhotic speakers say it pretty close to German); /ɔ/ is merged with /a/ in many westcoast American dialects, and the final shwa seems optional, since there's no other English word /porʃ/ that it could be.

**Executive summary**: You pays your money and you takes your choice.

Comment: `Americans, who are usually innocent of any linguistic knowledge` - Could you provide a reference for that? (I'm Dutch speaking Belgian, so it's nothing personal)

Comment: The American educational system doesn't teach anything useful about the English language, its grammar, pronunciation, or history, and does an extremely poor job of teaching other languages (which are not required; most people don't take them, and those who do rarely learn anything). So Americans basically don't know *Bahnhof* about language.

Comment: Wait, he asked for a reference.  Or are you using *yourself* as the reference?

Comment: Germans probably have more personal interactions with Brits than Americans, as averaged across the two populations. Making it more common for us to hear and reproduce their native pronunciation. Per kiamlaluno's comment, I remember Janis Joplin singing **porschiz** (plural of the single-syllable version). Which seemed right to me then, but now I'm quite well aware of the "correct" pronunciation now, even if I don't always use it (especially as a plural).

Comment: Americans do not merge /ɔr/ with /ar/. In General American, the vowels are not merged before /r/.  And the non-rhotic American dialects are ones that don't merge /ɔ/ with /a/. No American dialect I have heard would pronounce *stork* and *stark* the same.

Comment: True. These are independent phenomena. As for the reference, sure, why not? I've been saying this for years, in print and person. And experiencing it as a college teacher for almost 50 years. Americans are not taught, and by and large do not learn, anything accurate or useful about their own or other languages. They are mostly taught how not to irritate peevers, or at least peevers with the same set of peeves as their teachers.

Comment: @JohnLawler: While I understand the base for your concerns, this is  probably not the right forum to discuss them. It's largely a phenomenon that is to each their own. I speak Spanish fluently, for example, and while as a sole source of education, school wouldn't have been enough, I probably never would have attempted using it with friends and acquaintances (which is what really got me fluent) without it. Personal motivation is **always** a requirement.

Comment: Certainly it's not impossible to get educated. In my professorial career, the only students I ever encountered who had a clue about English grammar were of three types: non-native speakers, who'd had to learn English later; Americans who'd lived abroad or otherwise learned to speak another language; and Americans who'd taken Latin in high school.

Comment: @Peter Shor: As a "non-American", I pronounce *stork* and **stalk** the same, but I would never do that with **stork/stark** - making those two into homophones sounds typically American to my ear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: as far as I know, **stork** and **stark** are only homophones in [St. Louis.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_English_regional_phonology#St._Louis_and_vicinity) Not "typically American".

Comment: @Peter Shor: It's a safe bet you know more than me about different accents in the US. I guess what I really meant is my "British English ear" hears "stark" as wildly different to "stork", but I can imagine an American saying "stork" in a way that sounds like my British "stark". I'm quite prepared to accept that any such speaker would pronounce their American "stark" differently (but I personally might not easily register that difference unless they spoke both words slowly and clearly one after the other several times). In short, my stereotype isn't very accurate.

Comment: For a long time, when I heard it pronounced by BBC newsreaders/sports reporters, I used to think of it as 'Portia' like the Shakespeare character.

Comment: Typical _Economist_ headline: "Porsche Faces Life".

Answer (score 0):

Porsche is a German word, and the pronunciation of the 'e' at the end is a facsimile of the German pronunciation.

You could have found this out from the company's wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche

Comment: Sorry; I clarified the question to be clearer. I'm interested in if the general pronunciation is **changing** or if the differences I've observed are just regional or idiolect-driven.

Comment: @KevinK. It isn't changing. You're just encountering more people who know the correct pronunciation. There's nothing idiolectic about that, although choices as to whether or not correctly pronounce foreign words may be regional.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an element of hypercorrection here, where people may be more used to trying to get French words right by not pronouncing a final vowel.  Since the word is German, we need to pronounce the final vowel to be faithful to the original language.

Not everyone knows the right way to pronounce it, and too many people probably do not even care.