# What is the name of the ɔʏ sound?

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds, diphthongs, phonemes

What's the English name of the *oi* sound written as "eu" and commonly found in Germanic words like Deutschland, and names like Euler and von Neumann?

Comment: English speakers use the same sound in *Deutschland, Euler,* and *von Neumann* as in *toy, oiler,* and *choice*. People who know about [lexical sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set) might refer to it as the "choice vowel".

Comment: @Peter Shor: I'm sure you have more reason than me to pronounce *von Neumann's* name "correctly" - but I've always said "new-man", and no-one has ever corrected me. In my youth I used to read Mad magazine, so lots of people would have mentioned [Alfred E. Neuman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_E._Neuman). Have we all been getting it wrong, or does the doubling of the "n" make a difference there?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I've always heard *von Neumann* pronounced to rhyme with *toy man* (a slightly anglicized pronunciation), and Alfred E. Neuman pronounced *new man* (a more anglicized pronunciation). I don't believe the extra 'n' makes the difference; it's just how much the name has been anglicized. I know Americans named *Dougherty* can pronounce their name in at least three different ways (with a 'k', a 'g', and an 'h'), so the spelling doesn't tell you the pronunciation. Compare *Houston*, TX, and *Houston St.*, NYC. And the title character of *Young Frankenstein,* if you've seen it.

Comment: @Peter Shor: oic - so even your version isn't exactly what von Neumann would call *himself*. As with [Porsche](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51846/2637), I think my gut instinct would be to use fully-anglicised forms wherever these are at least "credible". For example, I always say *Dockertee* regardless of spelling or how others pronounce it (unless I'm speaking to the person thus named, in which case I usually make at least some effort to reproduce his own pronunciation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no single word for it. It’s the diphthong /ɔɪ/, a glide which ‘begins between back half-open and open positions, moves upwards and forwards towards [ɪ]; lips open rounded changing to neutral’ (‘Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language’).

Comment: It's rare that a sound in English has a special name that is other than its sound or its spelling, with schwa being the most common exception.

Comment: There are technical names for individual symbols, like _ash_ or _digraph_ for [æ], _caret_ for [ʌ], _barred I_ for [ɨ], or _U umlaut_ for [ü]. But diphthongs normally don't have special names, just because there are so many possible combinations, and most languages only use a few phonemic diphthongs; [English only has /oy/, /ay/, and /aw/](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf). Borrowed English words with the German <EU> spelling (or the German <ÄU> spelling, which is pronounced identically) are automatically pronounced with the English /oy/ phoneme.

Answer (score 0):

The *oi* sound is a phonemic diphthong, one of the three main German diphthongs.

It is a combination of the "open mid-back rounded vowel", like in "dog" in American English, and the "near-close near-front rounded vowel", which doesn't exist in American English.

The referenced links below have audio clips to hear the vowels.

Sources: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_phonology 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_rounded_vowel

Comment: That's not how most English speakers pronounce *book*. And there are a lot of English speakers who don't pronounce *dog* like that, either.

Comment: good point on _book_, I removed that comment. And I clarified that the vowel for _dog_ is specific to American English.

Comment: I'm only guessing but think it should be the **three main** German diphthongs. (It's unrelated to the question, agreed.)

Comment: No problem Kris, always happy to make grammar corrections! Especially when I'm posting in a grammar forum :P